# How to find questions to answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

It slowly dawns on me, after several years of using the SE network, that it doesn't do the obvious: present questions to me where I might be of maximum value. Specifically:

1. Questions on any of the SE sites that I'm a member of
2. That are at risk of going unanswered (ie, not minutes-old questions that will likely be answered by someone else)
3. That match my expertise (based on favourite tags, or tags of questions I've answered)
4. With a bias to higher rated questions

SE seems good at pointing me at "hot" questions (ie, ones with many answers), or all "unanswered" questions (regardless of whether they're relevant, or even answerable). This seems very inefficient from the perspective of maximising the number of answered questions (rather than maximising total number of answers).

Am I missing a feature somewhere? If so, are others missing it too?

Comment: OIC, there is an Unanswered/My Tags list - that does some of what I asked for.

Comment: If you're looking for a question list based on some algorithm that factors in questions you've already answered, and how well they did, the tags they were on, your favorite tags, etc. etc., you get a big fat +1 from me. Sounds a little ambitious, though.

Comment: @HodofHod: What you describe already exists.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ahh, and is that active on other sites besides SO?

Comment: @HodofHod: I don't know.  I've never had the need for it on other sites.  The lower velocity of questions on the slower sites basically means everyone sees the same home page.  On SO, everyone sees different questions on the home page.

Comment: OIC, it isn't. Well that explains why I haven't noticed it. @RobertHarvey Yeah, that makes sense to me, thanks!

Comment: Well, what do you know. It's been so long since I've looked at the SO front page (because it's always been completely irrelevant), I completely missed this change. I guess picking off questions down the bottom of the front page meets criterion 2 as well.

Comment: Still no mechanism for seeing interesting questions across all sites though, I guess.