# How can I contribute?

Tags: discussion

I've known about Stack Overflow for a while, since it comes up nearly every time I google for the solution to a programming issue I'm having. However, I've only recently created an account (on SO, not meta.SO) and started posting my own questions, since I'm having a lot of trouble with VBA.

Anyways, I've been overwhelmed by how helpful the SO community is! I really appreciate it, and I would love to give back somehow. The problem is, there are almost no questions on this site that I can answer helpfully. The broad majority of what experience I have is with Java, and all of the Java questions I see coming up are too advanced for me.

So I suppose this is a strange question, but is there anything else I can do to contribute and help SO? I feel bad giving nothing back!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/how-to-contribute-to-stack-overflow-besides-asking-and-answering?rq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/how-the-heck-am-i-supposed-to-contribute-to-this-site?rq=1

Comment: Also see these three posts about finding answerable questions: [How to find questions to answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132900/how-to-find-questions-to-answer); [How to find the right questions that I can answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/how-to-find-the-right-questions-that-i-can-answer); [Where can I find questions to which I might know an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77482/where-can-i-find-questions-to-which-i-might-know-an-answer)

Answer (score 6):

You can:

- Continue to ask questions. Really, we need questions to give answers to!
- Edit existing posts. If you see a post that could do with some language polishing (spelling mistakes, grammar, etc.) or formatting improvements, go ahead and improve it!
- Specialize. There are always questions about a subject *you* happen to know something about, but others don't. You just have to find that subject. It'll be there, don't worry.
- Help improve the [tag wikis](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/) (create new ones for those that don't have one yet). Each tag has a tag wiki associated with it, as well as an excerpt. When you mouse-over a tag it shows the excerpt, and when you click on the `info` link you are taken to the wiki page.
- Vote up good questions and answers, vote down those that are bad. Give feedback to new users to help them improve their posts.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is vote-up questions and answers you find interesting and helpful.

Also down-vote unhelpful answers and questions which aren't useful.

Edit posts to make them more readable and, thus, more useful.

Help create or improve tag wikis.

Fix inappropriate tags on questions; add missing tags.

There's lots to do to make Stack Overflow and the rest of Stack Exchange better besides answering questions.

Comment: What do you mean by help create or improve tag wikis?

Comment: @AustinR: Each tag on SO has a description attached to them, and an excerpt. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info for an example (click the 'show excerpt' link too). You can suggest improvements for these.